# adding "stasm_lib.h" to my project, opencv, face feature detection

Tags: opencv

I’m beginner in C++ and OpenCV. As you know stasm is a C++ software library for finding features in faces that introduced in: http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm I want to use stasm 4.1 library for image recognition. I read manual stasm but I don’t understand how add "stasm_lib.h" to my project!! Please guide me step by step for locating face landmarks, after running I got this error:
cannot open include file: fetal error C1083 'stasm_lib.h' No such file or directory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "stasm_lib.h"

int main()
{
  static const char* path = "../data/testface.jpg";

cv::Mat_<unsigned char> img(cv::imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));

if (!img.data)
{
    printf("Cannot load %s\n", path);
    exit(1);
}

int foundface;
float landmarks[2 * stasm_NLANDMARKS]; // x,y coords

if (!stasm_search_single(&foundface, landmarks,
                         (char*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, path, "../data"))
{
    printf("Error in stasm_search_single: %s\n", stasm_lasterr());
    exit(1);
}

if (!foundface)
     printf("No face found in %s\n", path);
else
{
    // draw the landmarks on the image as white dots
    stasm_force_points_into_image(landmarks, img.cols, img.rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < stasm_NLANDMARKS; i++)
        img(cvRound(landmarks[i*2+1]), cvRound(landmarks[i*2])) = 255;
}

cv::imshow("stasm minimal", img);
cv::waitKey();
return 0;
}`
```

Thanks a lot